# Angular directive HostListener Event on page load or show/hide section to update model value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, frontend

I have an angualr directive created to convert lowerCase to UpperCase (I know there is an angular pipe for this, but I created this directive to understand the concepts. I actually want similar kind of functionality for other directive). But for some reason, this directive is not called initially for pre-defined model value. However, this is triggered when I update the input text box manually.

I wanted an angular directive to run on page load or show/hide section of the component.

In this example, I wanted to pre-populate the "User Name" text box with "TEST" on page load or show/hide section of the component (this show/hide section will show or hide based on the response from the Service call) because I initialized model value with "test" and defined `appUpperCase` directive on input text box.

How do we tell angular directive to run on page load or show/hide section of the component.

Here is the `appUpperCase` directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appUpperCase]'
})
export class UpperCaseDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(private control: NgControl) { }

  processInput(value: any) {
    return value.toUpperCase();
  }

  @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
  ngModelChange(value: any) {
    console.log(`directive called ${value}`);
    this.control.valueAccessor.writeValue(this.processInput(value));
  }

  @HostListener('keydown.backspace', ['$event'])
  keydownBackspace(value: any) {
    this.control.valueAccessor.writeValue(this.processInput(value));
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Here is my html file:

```
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="UserName" class="col-2 col-form-label">User Name:</label>
      <div class="col-4">
      <input class="form-control" id="UserName" name="userName" required [(ngModel)]="userName" appUpperCase>
      Model: {{ userName }}
      </div>
    </div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
      Search
    </button>
  </form>
```

and in component file.

```
 userName: any;
  constructor() {
    this.userName = 'test';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why you're using `HostListener` (first of all, for keydown.backspace listener, you don't receive a value in the listener but the event).

Why not just listen to the valueChanges stream of the control, and update it there?

Also, you should use `ReactiveFormsModule` so you can get the value.

```js
// directive.ts

import { Directive, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { distinctUntilChanged, startWith, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appUpperCase]',
})
export class UpperCaseDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private _destroyed$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private control: NgControl) {}

  processInput(value: any) {
    return value.toUpperCase();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._destroyed$.next();
    this._destroyed$.complete();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.control.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(this.control.value),
        distinctUntilChanged((first, second) => {
          return this.processInput(first) === this.processInput(second);
        }),
        takeUntil(this._destroyed$)
      )
      .subscribe((value) => {
        this.control.control.setValue(this.processInput(value));
      });
  }
}
```

```js
// component.ts
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  userName = new FormControl('test');

  constructor() {}

  submitForm() {
    console.log(this.userName.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<!--component.html-->
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="UserName" class="col-2 col-form-label">User Name:</label>
    <div class="col-4">
      <input
        [formControl]="userName"
        class="form-control"
        id="UserName"
        name="userName"
        required
        appUpperCase
      />
      Model: {{ userName.value }}
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Cristian-Florin Calina! Your solution works to update text box only but not actual model value on page load. If I try to edit the text box then only it updates the model with missing one character to update. for ex, with your solution, TESTA in input box converts to TESTa. This is invalid because TESTA in input box should convert to TESTA in model.

Comment: I see, I've changed the logic then. You will call setValue with the updated value on the control only if uppercase is not the same as the current value. Hope it makes sense. Please try the code above :)

Comment: Thanks, Appreciated your response. Updated code works on page load. But its not working when the values comes dynamically, for ex, if I have a submit button clicked, then only I want to show this name field and the value comes from the back end Service Call and there is no page reload here. How do I achieve it?

Comment: Then you should use ReactiveFormsModule from angular. I've made yet another edit. Please have a look.